# Error in bertopic package installation. ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bert-language-model, python-packaging

While downloading pip install bertopic, I encountered this error:

```
Collecting bertopic
  Using cached bertopic-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
Collecting pandas>=1.1.5
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (11.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.41.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly>=4.7.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (5.8.0)
Collecting hdbscan>=0.8.29
  Using cached hdbscan-0.8.29.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.22.2.post1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: umap-learn>=0.5.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (0.5.3)
Collecting numpy>=1.20.0
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (14.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: sentence-transformers>=0.4.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.29->bertopic) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.29->bertopic) (0.29.28)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.29->bertopic) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from plotly>=4.7.0->bertopic) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.22.2.post1->bertopic) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sentencepiece in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (0.1.97)
Requirement already satisfied: transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (4.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub>=0.4.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.6.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pynndescent>=0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (0.5.8)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.49 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (0.51.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (2.28.1)
Collecting packaging>=20.9
  Using cached packaging-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\bagala\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (3.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.49->umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (0.34.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.49->umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (50.3.1.post20201107)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.14,>=0.11.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (2022.10.31)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\bagala\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from nltk->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (8.1.3)
Collecting torch>=1.6.0
  Using cached torch-1.13.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (162.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torchvision->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from click->nltk->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (1.25.11)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ygments (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ygments (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [40 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_prediction_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\hdbscan\tests
  running build_ext
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
  cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
  cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
  cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
  building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
  Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build hdbscan
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b6bgdffd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\BAGALA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q9ji0sg\hdbscan_ad2c434de3ee4edbb0dd1201827e9ed2\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ygments (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

I have the following versions of python and pip:
Python 3.8.5
pip 23.0.1
I also have visual basic c++ installed
I am running on Jupyternotebook.

I was able to install hbdscan using

```
conda install -c conda-forge hbdscan
```

And added the following as sugggested in other related threads:

```
pip install python-dev-tools --user --upgrade
!pip install bertopic --no-build-isolation --no-binary :all:
```

and it is still not working.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

First be sure to have the latest version of pip `pip install --upgrade pip`

then have you tried simply doing a `pip install hdbscan` then `pip install bertopic`

If that dont work and you are on `Windows`, install the `Visual Studio Build` Tools https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ during the install be sure to check `C++ Build Tools` `Windows 10 SDK C++` x`64/x86 build tools`

then reboot, then `pip install bertopic`

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of these commands worked for me:

```
conda create -n BRenv python=3.8

conda activate BRenv  

conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan

pip install bertopic
```